# Check environments timezone settings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I want to be able to check against the environments timezone settings and if its not a US timezone then I will handle the datetime with a more global format. For example. I have a user in America their settings is MM-DD-YYYY now if I have another user in Canada they want to see DD-MM-YYYY but instead of just giving them different versions I would rather have some logic that grabs the timezone and compares it against something and then that determines how the datetime will be handled.

```
if(System.TimeZone.StandardTime = US)
  {
   objOrderEntryItemUsageReport.VarShipDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datpkrShipDate.Value).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY"); 
  }
else
  {
   objOrderEntryItemUsageReport.VarShipDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datpkrShipDate.Value).ToString("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

I just don't know the best way to check the environments timezone settings and even how to compare it to see if its a US timezone?

Would I need to create a dictionary with the American timezones in it and then do a while loop through that dictionary to see if the current timezone matches and if not then handle it like an international user?

Answer (score 3):

The user's time zone and the user's culture are entirely separate matters.

It's not clear where this code is running, but basically you want to use the appropriate `CultureInfo`, and then you can use `DateTime.TryParse` specifying the culture. You can use `TryParseExact` specifying a standard format of `d` for "short date format". (Likewise for calls to `ToString`... just pass in the culture and a format of `d`.)

Alternatively - and preferably - use a [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you don't need to parse the value *at all*. (Given your names, it's possible that you're already using a `DateTimePicker`, so it's unclear why you're calling `Convert.ToDateTime` - the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is already of type `DateTime`.

Then, don't convert it to a string later either - your `VarShipDate` property shouldn't be a string property, it should be a `DateTime` property. That's what you're trying to represent, after all. Avoid string conversions as far as you possibly can. They are error-prone, culturally sensitive, and basically full of potential fail.

Additionally, I would strongly advise against using `System.TimeZone` - use `System.TimeZoneInfo`, which is effectively the replacement for `TimeZone`.

Comment: I will have to check on the CultureInfo. I never came across that before.

Comment: ok so just a quick check it seems I can check the CultureInfo and if its not set to MM-DD-YYYY then I can change the way I am handling datetime correct?

Comment: @NitroFrost: No, you shouldn't be specifying `MM-dd-yyyy` at all. Let .NET handle the best format, *if you even need to format it*. See my edited answer - I strongly suspect you shouldn't be using string parsing or formatting at all.

Comment: I do have a datetimepicker. So in the Designer I want to have the display logic for the date time picker to change depending on the local of the user.

Comment: @NitroFrost: The *designer* is just what you see while you're coding. You mean the UI in front of the end user, right? .NET should handle that for you automatically. You can test it by changing your computer's regional settings (watch the system clock to see the changes take effect) and then rerunning your application.

Comment: By _designer_ I did mean end user. Currently how it is set up, when ever a datetimepicker is used this logic is called.

            objOrderEntryItemUsageReport.VarMeasurement = atcodMeasurement.Value.ToString();
            if (datpkrShipDate.Value == null)
                objOrderEntryItemUsageReport.VarShipDate = string.Empty;
            else
                objOrderEntryItemUsageReport.VarShipDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datpkrShipDate.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

This is something I am working on from another user and hardcoding seems like the very wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Just saw your edit Jon yea because of that hard coding it won't handle it that way. Perhaps if I just remove the hard coding should it display probably for me?

Comment: You should remove *all* your string handling, by the looks of it. The value is inherently a date, right? So why are you treating it as a string at all? And why are you calling `Convert.ToDateTime` when `datpkrShipDate.Value` is already of type `DateTime`? It's really important to separate out the inherent values from a textual representation. Keep data in its natural form until you *have* to display it to a user, and then let the framework do most of the hard work... and for DateTimePicker, you don't need to work with strings at all.

Comment: Thanks Jon, everything you said makes perfect sense. I am testing some things out now so far it looks like it is handling everything fine. Currently its not retrieving a record but that might be my mistake I am double checking that now. My worry is it won't retrieve records accordingly because they **were** being handled as a string.